# Trying to get an if statement to display Login buttons when the person is not logged in and logout button when they are

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to get it soo that when they are not logged in it displays both login buttons but when they are logged in it displays only the logout button.

```
<% 
  if ( request.getParameter( "username" ) == null )
{   
    <ul class="CustLogin">
    <li><a href="CustomerLoginPage.jsp">Customer Login</a></li></ul>
    <ul class="MangLogin">
    <li><a href="ManagerLoginPage.jsp">Manager Login</a></li></ul>
}
  else
  {
    <ul class="Logout">;
    <li><a href="LoggingOut.jsp"> Logout</a></li></ul>
  }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, Your JSP tags has to be separated from the html as below

```
<% 
if ( request.getParameter( "username" ) == null )
{   
%>
    <ul class="CustLogin">
    <li><a href="CustomerLoginPage.jsp">Customer Login</a></li></ul>
    <ul class="MangLogin">
    <li><a href="ManagerLoginPage.jsp">Manager Login</a></li></ul>
<%
}
else
{
%>
    <ul class="Logout">;
    <li><a href="LoggingOut.jsp"> Logout</a></li></ul>
<%
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can only work when for each page interaction you do a post/get request containing the "username" as a parameter (for logged in users).

The solution would be :

```
<%if ( request.getParameter( "username" ) == null ){%> 
  <ul class="CustLogin">
  <li><a href="CustomerLoginPage.jsp">Customer Login</a></li></ul>
  <ul class="MangLogin">
  <li><a href="ManagerLoginPage.jsp">Manager Login</a></li></ul>
<%}else{%>
  <ul class="Logout">;
  <li><a href="LoggingOut.jsp"> Logout</a></li></ul>
<%}%>
```

There are two issues in your code though:

1. Mixing logic layer with presentation layer is very bad and was long discouraged (One among many alternatives is to use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) instead)
2. The way to track if a user is logged in or not is not at all safe in terms of security and can easily get spoofed. You should try and apply other means to track logged in users.( [HTTP Basic Authentication, Form-Based Authentication, Digest Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html#gkbsa))

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use cookie for this instead of request.getParameter ( i believe that this variable will exist only when you'll redirect the user from a page with a form to another one, but if the user go to another page, then this variable will no longer exists ). On the method you use for the login, add this :

```
setCookie("user","loggedin",7);
```

and in the method you use for logging yout, add this :

```
setCookie("user","loggedout",7);
```

The setCookie function :

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Then on your JSP page you could have smthing like this

```
<% 
  if ( getCookie(user) == "loggedout")
{   
%>
    <ul class="CustLogin">
    <li><a href="CustomerLoginPage.jsp">Customer Login</a></li></ul>
    <ul class="MangLogin">
    <li><a href="ManagerLoginPage.jsp">Manager Login</a></li></ul>
<%
}
  else
  {
%>
    <ul class="Logout">;
    <li><a href="LoggingOut.jsp"> Logout</a></li></ul>
 <%
  }
%>
```

With this function to get the value of a given cookie :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```